# how to load a html file with all style and script files into a modal?

Tags: html, laravel, iframe, modal-dialog

I want to load one page inside another(I'm working with laravel ). I have a link on the page, when user clicks on a button, a bootstrap popup modal will be shown. So I need to load the whole page (including scripts and styles) in this bootstrap popup modal. The problem is my loaded page in popup, doesn't work correctly.. and I don't know how to load my scripts into my modal.. I have tried with iframes but it doesn't work either with the error 'X-Frame-Options' with 'deny' value..

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

thanks with regards

its a sample of my code:

```
<a class="btn"
   title="View"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#cv_view">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
  </a>

    {{-- modal--}}
<div class="modal fade"
     id="cv_view"
     tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <iframe
                  :src="cv.viewRoute"
                   style="zoom:3"
                   width="100%"
                   height="250"
                   frameborder="0">
           </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                    Close
            </button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Well `X-Frame-Options: Deny` says your page must not be displayed in _any_ kind of (i)frames anywhere ever ... so you first of all need to fix _that_. (And if you don’t know where to specify this in your system, or what an appropriate value could be - research please.)

Comment: It will be helpful if you disclose some code,  especially the web page you want to display

Comment: thanks @CBroeits for your response.. its a page of our company to show in an iframe.. so there is no way to rewrite the header?? because i check so many ways and no one of them did not change the header..